# SMB network printing with blank password?

Tags: networking, printing, samba

I have a PC wire-connected to printer(Windows 10) and an other PC(ubuntu 18.04).
I connected and registered printer from ubuntu via SMB. But when I try to print, it asks for username and password.

Problem is that the Windows PC neither have account password, nor it is set up to require password when sharing. smbclient can list all sharing of the windows PC with only username, but it seems system-config-printer does not like blank password.

Is there anything I can do, or is there any alternative I can use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug which can hopefully be fixed soon for stable releases:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1849859